# How to write JSON Response in if condition using php in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-select2

I Have written the following `function` in the `Categories` Controller. which check the `categories` in the `database` and returns a `response`. Now if the `parent_cat_id: "1"` then I want to show the `select2` field from the `Form`

```
public function parent_categories(){
        $table = "store_categories";
        $selectData = "id AS ID, cat_title AS TEXT,parent_cat_id";
        $search = $this->input->get('q');
        $where = array('status' => "enabled");
        if(isset($search) && !empty($search)){
            $field = "Title";
            $Result = $this->Common_model->select_fields_where_like_join($table,$selectData,"",$where,FALSE,$field,$search);
        }else{
            $Result = $this->Common_model->select_fields_where_like_join($table,$selectData,"",$where);
        }
        if(empty($Result)){
            $emptyArray = array(
                array(
                    'ID' => 0,
                    'TEXT' => "No Record Found"
                )
            );
            print json_encode($emptyArray);
            return;
        }
        print json_encode($Result);
    }
```

> This is the `select2` Field in `form`

I have tried something like this but I am sure this not works. I have write this `<?php if(parent_cat_id == "1"){?>` for you people to understand what i am saying that how to perform action like this on `JSON response`

```
<?php if(parent_cat_id == "1"){?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="form-group">
          <label for="Header Text" class="control-label">Parent Category</i>
          </label>
          <select name="parent_categories" id="parent_categories" class="form-control select2" ></select>
       </div>
       <!-- /.form-group -->
    </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

> This is the JSON Response

```
{  
    ID:"2",
    TEXT:"waqas",
    parent_cat_id:"1"
}
```

Comment: I think your question is unclear, Please be more specific here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$emptyArray = array(
                array(
                    'ID' => 0,
                    'TEXT' => "No Record Found"
                )
            );

$json = json_decode(json_encode($emptyArray));
echo $json->parent_cat_id;
```

First off you need to use json_decode instead of encode in order to be able to work with the json data. Json decode will turn it into a object or an associative array for you which you can then use as you please.

Comment: It not works. the select2 field is in the views how can I check this in if statement?